# Single quote string string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, string-interpolation

I am trying to set an email address within ActionMailer with Rails. Before it was hard coded, but we want to make them ENV variables now so we don't need to amend code each time an email changes.

Here is how it's currently defined:

```
from = '"Name of Person" <email@email.com>'
```

I've tried setting the email as an environment variable using `ENV['EMAIL']` but I'm having no luck even with `#{ENV['EMAIL'}`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Action Mailer Basics - Sending Email With Name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-with-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use string interpolation with single-quoted strings in Ruby.

But double-quoted strings can!

```
from = "'Name of Person' <#{ENV['EMAIL']}>"
```

But if you want to keep your double-quotes wrapping the `Name of Person`, you can escape them with a backslash `\`:

```
from = "\"Name of Person\" <#{ENV['EMAIL']}>"
```

Or use string concatenation:

```
from = '"Name of Person" <' + ENV['EMAIL'] + '>'
# but I find it ugly
```

Comment: works a dream. Could of swore I tried this yesterday but was getting nil. All works now :) I shall accept once time elapses.

Comment: just btw you dont have to explicitly put + sign in order to concatenate strings in ruby `'"Name of Person" <' ENV['EMAIL'] '>'` will work aswell, however id advocate to use first/second example provided by MrYoshiji

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Sometimes you *need* to interpolate ruby inside single quotes (for example, in d3 js svg parameters, which only allow single-quote properties).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to embed double quotes in an interpolated string you can use % notation delimiters (which Ruby stole from Perl), e.g.

```
from = %|"Name of Person", <#{ENV['EMAIL']}>|
```

or

```
from = %("Name of Person", <#{ENV['EMAIL']}>)
```

Just pick a delimiter after the `%` that isn't already in your string.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `format`. I have not seen it used as commonly in Ruby as in other languages (e.g. C, Python), but it works just as well:

```
from = format('"Name of Person", <%s>', ENV["EMAIL"])
```

Alternative syntax using the `%` operator:

```
from = '"Name of Person", <%s>' % ENV["EMAIL"]
```

Here is the documentation for `format` (aka `sprintf`):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format

Comment: Using `%` is more idiomatic.